# How to execute code, while promise is resolving

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Assuming I have a function `foo()` which returns a `promise`. How would I "start" the `async` function `foo()`, execute some code while `foo()` is resolving, and then go on with the rest of the code after `foo()` resolved?

```
// start async function foo
const somePromise = foo(); // do not use await here in order to execute the following lines
// synchronous code
const a = ....;
const b = ....;
// and then, go on with the rest of the code after the synchronous (const a = ..., const b = ...) and asynchronous (foo()) parts have finished
if(somePromise resolved) { // how to check for resolved promise here
    // go on
    const bar = a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty funny you even use the word `then` in your question, but:

```js
const somePromise = foo();
// do something synchronous while foo() is resolving
// and then, go on with the rest of the code after the synchronous and asynchronous parts have finished

somePromise.then(() => {
  // go on
});
```

You're better off handling this immediately;

```js
foo().then(() => {
  // go on
});

// This happens synchronously
```

Variant of the first, with `await`:

```js
const somePromise = foo();
// do something synchronous while foo() is resolving
// and then, go on with the rest of the code after the synchronous and asynchronous parts have finished

await somePromise;
// go on
```

Comment: Ah, I thought this is "oldschool" and there might be a way to do this with await or something :)

Comment: @four-eyes in this case await does the opposite of what you want. You explicitly mentioned you *didn't* want to await.

Comment: But you can await later, so i'll add an example for that too.

Comment: Ah, I was aiming for the last example. There is no need to assign `foo()` to a variable? Weird :)

Comment: @CherryDT. You're right! All my examples are wrong

Comment: @CherryDT Fixed both!

Comment: Perfect. - Another thing though, I just want to point out that in the case of doing a `.then`/`await` some time later on and you have _other_ `await`s in the middle, there is a gotcha with errors - you will get an unhandled promise rejection because node won't know that you are going to call `.then`/`await` (or `.catch`) some time later.

Comment: Yeah that's the spicy part and probably why I'd recommend the middle solution. Annoying error when you know what you're doing.

Comment: @CherryDT Doesn't even have to be an `await` in the middle. *Any* code that throws an exception between the creation of the promise and its `await`ing can cause a crash (due to the unhandled promise rejection, even if you catch the thrown exception).